# $(this) referring to window, not div that called function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I have a function that dynamically inserts a close button into divs as they are added to the page.

```
//Insert Close ALERT WINDOW button
function addCloseAlertButton(){
    if ($(".alert").find('.closeAlerts').length < 1){
        $(".alert").append('<div class="closeAlerts" onclick="closeAlert()">Dismiss</div>');
    }

};
```

And the function called by onclick:

```
//Close Alert Function
function closeAlert(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
};
```

But clicking on the div doesn't remove the alert div as I expected. When I `console.log($(this))` in the function, I found that `$(this)` was referring to the entire `window` and `$(this).parent` came up empty, so that is why the function isn't working.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how I can make it so `$(this)` refers to the calling div, not the entire `window`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't use inline JS to do that. Instead use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '.closeAlerts', function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Why is this better?  If you have a "don't do this" on a question you really need a darn good reason.... I don't think style is a good one -- what else you got?

Comment: @Hogan - I thought that by now this was pretty much common knowledge. I guess not. Check out http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/86589/why-should-i-avoid-inline-scripting

Comment: @j08691 - You are totally missing my point. My comment is not "Why do you do it this way?" Making a snide point about how I should know -- is exactly to my point.  **My point** is this is a bad answer -- you said "don't do that" and you don't say why.  I know why, you know why, and I guess EvilSyn knows why, BUT *any given reader of this page looking for an answer to their question* might not.  Thus this is a bad answer unless it explains why the original question was flawed and how to fix this flaw.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your

```
onclick="closeAlert()"
```

with this:

```
onclick="closeAlert.call(this)"
```

and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Because you're using inline event handlers. If you want to keep the handler function separate, this would be one possibility:

```
function addCloseAlertButton() {
    if ($(".alert").find('.closeAlerts').length < 1) {
        $('<div class="closeAlerts">Dismiss</div>')
            .appendTo('.alert')
            .click(closeAlert);
    }

};

function closeAlert() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set `this` as parameter in function

```
<div class="closeAlerts" onclick="closeAlert(this)">Dismiss</div>
```

And `this` will be your `div` object.

But I'm not reccomend you to use embedded javascript code in html elements. Try to separate js code from html.